# R is "Shrinking" HTML files?

Tags: html, r

Has anyone ever had this problem where R is "shrinking" the size of HTML files?

I created these maps in R:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
id = 1:1000
long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 1000, 0.1085246 , 0.1)
lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 1000, 0.009036273 , 0.1)
my_data_1 = data.frame(id, lat, long)
id = 1:1000
long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 1000, 0.1085246 , 0.1)
lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 1000, 0.009036273 , 0.1)
my_data_2 = data.frame(id, lat, long)


map1 = my_data_1 %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addHeatmap(lng=~long,lat=~lat,max=100,radius=20,blur=10)

map2 = my_data_2 %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addHeatmap(lng=~long,lat=~lat,max=100,radius=20,blur=10)

map3 = my_data_1 %>% 
    leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())
```

I then saved them as HTML files:

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(plotly)

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(map1), "m1.html")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(map2), "m2.html")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(map3), "m3.html")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(map4), "m4.html")
```

When I then tried to render these HTML files in an interactive dashboard in R:

```
Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------
   
### map 1

<object type="text/html" data="m1.html"></object>

### map 2

<object type="text/html" data="m2.html"></object>

### map 3

<object type="text/html" data="m3.html"></object>
```

These maps seem to have "shrunk" in R:

[image]

- Does anyone know why this is happening and what I might be able to do to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried specifying `height=` and `width` values for your `<object>` tag? You should be able to set them however larger you want them (in pixels). HTML pages don't have a natural "size." Just like the content you see in a web browser changes as you resize the window.

Comment: @ Mr. Flick: Thank you for this suggestion! Did you mean something like this? <object type="text/html"  width="200" height="300" data="m1.html"></object> ?

Comment: I wonder if there is some option for "auto fitting"? thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suggesting. It doesn't make sense to have an autofitting option because the content doesn't have a native size. It will fill whatever window you make for it. The natural size is something a designer needs to set.

Comment: Since I did not know what size to choose, I just chose a very large size so that the map would fit on the screen better. Example: <object type="text/html" width="5000" height="5000" data="m1.html"></object> .... however, I feel this is not a very efficient way to do this...

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you are finding this solution:

```
<style>
.one {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>


Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------
   
### map 1

<object class="one" type="text/html" data="m1.html"></object>

### map 2

<object class="one" type="text/html" data="m2.html"></object>

### map 3

<object class="one" type="text/html" data="m3.html"></object>
```

[image]

Comment: @ Manro: thank you so much for your answer! if you have time, could you please show me how the whole solution would work for all 3 maps? I am a bit confused with the <!--- code ---> command. thank you so much!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 Ready. ```<!--- code --->``` was a code comment.